# changing language on ipad3

Tags: ipad, language

I changed language on the iPad3 from english to italian, but I noticed that a few things remain in english. For instance, day and time in locked screen, as well as in the calendar. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: What do you mean by day and time? Names of days like Monday, Tuesday…?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to change the Region Format settings in Settings > General > International ?

[image: International Settings on iPhone]

You should be able to change it to Italian.

***Note :*** this is an iPhone capture but it is exactly on the same place on the iPad. It is easier to put an iPhone capture in a post.